# c# binding IDictionary with Listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to windows form and learning. 
I have a simple code with a form populated with listbox1. I am trying to populate it by binding it to IDictionary instance.

```
static IDictionary<string, string> Bind_Data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    Binding myBinding = new Binding("DataSource", Bind_Data, "Key");   

    listBox1.DataBindings.Add(myBinding);
```

I am getting the following error when I run this code.

> error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor
>   'Key' on object
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
>   threw the following exception:'Object does not match target type.'
>   ---> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)

Really appreciate if someone can help me understand this error.

I can use

```
listBox1.DataSource=new Binding(Bind_Data, null);
listBox1.ValueMemeber="Key";
listBox1.DisplayMember="Value";
```

But I want to use Binding

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MSDN docs for that constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Binding__ctor_System_String_System_Object_System_String_

The data source argument can only be certain objects - the Dictionary type doesn't implement IList, which I suspect is the reason you are getting the above exception.

If your underlying type **must** be a Dictionary, you may want to wrap it in a custom class which implements IList so that you get your desired binding, otherwise just use the second style you have above

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is not necessary I use Dictionary. But, I am trying to figure out how to use Binding as anything I do throws this exception.